# Stripping the Ticket ID out of a String: "[Ticket ID: 9884219]"

Tags: php, regex, numbers, strip, ticket-system

In my support ticket system, replies are sent to the user and the subject includes `[Ticket ID: ######]` in it.

What could I use to strip the ###### out of there by supplying the entire title?

For example, a function that will turn this:

> [Ticket ID: 600238] Forgot password, reset it please :(

into this:

> 600238

The subjects can start with any characters, though the ticket ID brackets are separated from the subject itself using a space.

Is there an RegEx to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`preg_match`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php).

```
if (preg_match("/\[Ticket ID: (\d+)\]/", $input, $matches)) {
    $ticket_id = $matches[1];
}
```

Comment: preg_match("\[Ticket ID: (\d+)\]", "RE: [Ticket ID: 5890684] Hello World", $matches) does not work.

Comment: You need to escape the brackets in the regex. My answer includes this, whereas your test code does not.

Comment: I do have them escaped, but Stack Overflow removed them in my comment.

Comment: Using Subject: RE: [Ticket ID: 30649722] Hello

Ticket ID Found: 

Items in Array: 0

Comment: @Bailey: Have you considered enabling error_reporting when things don't work?

Comment: @mario I wasn't expecting an error, as the script didn't stop and I don't use preg_match, but thanks for that reminder, haha. Error: "Delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash"

Comment: Works when I try it in Patterns.app

Comment: I did after your edit. I still get this error: "Delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash" I have exactly what you have in my PHP script. Perhaps PHP is stripping something?

Comment: @Bailey I've edited my answer to account for that (I think; I'm more used to using regex in Java which does not require beginning and ending slash delimeters).

Comment: NOW it works. I got the entire "[Ticket ID: ??]" but I will just strip the unnecessary parts out.

Comment: The numeric ID is already in `$matches[1]` - (the whole match is in `$matches[0]`). Use this statement instead:  `$ticket_id = $matches[1];`

Answer (score 1):

'[' ']' have spacial meaning in regular expression, hence you have to escape them in the regular expression.
The regular expression you need is `/\[Ticket ID: [\d]{6}\]/`

You may want to use [\s]+ in between the words if not sure about number of spaces in between the words.

This Regular expression will give you whole `Ticket ID: ######` And again you have to extract the number.

RegExp are very powerful and here you can learn more about RegExp [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp)